# Replacing "%" in a variable

Tags: variables, batch-file

Quite simple problem, no soloution yet:

```
C:\> Set var=^%test^%
C:\> Echo %var%
%test%

C:\> Echo %var:^%=-%
%test%

C:\> Why is this not producing -test-?
```

I tried doubling and removing the carrot(`^`) with little success. Any suggests (or solutions) appreciated.

Mona

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to replace `%` using SET search and replace is to use delayed expansion. It is impossible to escape the `%` in a way that lets you use normal expansion.

Rules for `%` are different in batch vs command prompt.

From within a batch script, `%` is escaped by doubling it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "var=%%test%%"
set var
set "var=!var:%%=-!"
set var
```

--OUTPUT--

```
var=%test%
var=-test-
```

From the command prompt, it is actually impossible to escape `%`. If text enclosed within quotes does not equal a variable name, then the percents are left in place. Also, an unpaired percent is also left in place. The code below assumes variable `test` does not exist:

```
C:\test>cmd /v:on
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\test>set "var=%test%"

C:\test>set var
var=%test%

C:\test>set "var=!var:%=-!"

C:\test>set var
var=-test-

C:\test>
```

If variable `test` does exist, then you can set your initial `var` value using something like:

```
c:\test>set "var=%^test%"
var=%test%
```

The caret "escapes" the next character, so it is consumed, leaving the correct value. It could be placed anywhere within the percents. But the code assumes variable `^test` does not exist. If it did, then it would simply expand the value, as below:

```
C:\test>set "^test=Hello world"

C:\test>set ^^
^test=Hello world

C:\test>set "var=%^test%"

C:\test>set var
var=Hello world

C:\test>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set var=%%test%%
set a=var:%%=
echo var is %var%
echo var%%= is !%a%!
```

this should work... %% not ^% escapes %'s in batch files. in a batch file, ^% is really escaping the char after the %, in this case the newline.

Comment: `^% is really escaping the char after the %, in this case the newline` - That's wrong `^%test^%`, the second caret will be used as part of the variable name `test^` and after expanding the variable(or in this case the complete part will stay unchanged) both carets escaping the following character which is also in both cases the percent sign, without any further effect.

Comment: try the line `set a=^%test^%` followed by the line `hello world`, a will be set to `hello world`.